# Query database in Django for sum of two fields, sorting wrong

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got an object that have the counts for connections in twitter and facebook saved in the object's table. I'm trying to sort a list of these objects by the combined sum of the facebook and twitter counts using the .extra field.

Some of the twitter / facebook fields are empty (None) so the combined is blank. This is causing some issues, and these blank ones are being sorted first. Is there any way to have these blank fields sorted as if they were 0?

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(
    setup_complete=1, active=1
).exclude(
    Q(background_image__isnull=True) | Q(background_image__exact='')
).extra(
    select={'total_count':'twitter_count + facebook_count'},order_by=['-total_count']
)[:99]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested, but can you do this?

```
annotate(total_count=Sum(twitter_count) + Sum(facebook_count))
```

If not, you may need to do it in the model. For example, in the model add a

```
def get_total(self):
    if twitter_count == None and facebook_count == None:
        return 0
    elif twitter_count != None and facebook_count != None:
        return twitter_count + facebook_count
    elif twitter_count != None:
        return twitter_count
    else:
        return facebook_count
total_count = property(get_total)
```

Then in your query:

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(
    setup_complete=1, active=1
).exclude(
    Q(background_image__isnull=True) | Q(background_image__exact='')
).annotate(
    total_count=Sum(total)
).order_by=('-total')
)[:99]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have two integer fields in the Page table. I want to order_by a sum of those fields. Could you expand how I'd use annotate()?  Not seeing the same use as extra()

Comment: This gives me a FieldError
Cannot resolve keyword 'total_count' into field. (I changed total to total_count in the annotate area since I didn't know where total came from)

Comment: And for the first Sum + Sum suggestion, I get this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Sum' and 'Sum'

Comment: What about `annotate(total_count=Sum(twitter_count + facebook_count))`?

Comment: Or, can you still use extra() like this: `.extra(
    select={'total_count':'Sum(twitter_count + facebook_count)'},order_by=['-total_count']
)`

Comment: the annotate throws an error and the extra doesn't return any results that contain counts. Only None

Comment: Damn, sorry, Brenden. That must mean there are over 99 records with a NULL. If you can get to the database and can change the fields to ALLOW NULL = False, it should update all of the NULL records to 0. I'm not sure if that would cause other problems in your system. It is dangerous to make fundamental changes like this. Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is to do a raw query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5250/discussion-between-brenden-and-furbeenator)